# Microsoft Edge window.open() not honoring width height on the second popup

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I'm on Windows 10 Build 10586.122, and the window.open method in the new Edge browser isn't behaving as per the specification.

If you use the example code in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(v=vs.85).aspx, and click to open a new window, it will open a new window with correct width and height.But if I open second new window from the first pop-up with different width and hieght, It will completely ignore the width and height but have a same size from the first pop-up.

For example: I have 2 files blow

File 1: sample1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body onclick="myOpen();">
        <p>Click this page and window.open() is called.</p>
        <script>
            function myOpen() {
                window.open("Sample2.html", null, "height=200, width=400, status=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

File 2: sample2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body onclick="myOpen();">
        <p>Click this page and window.open() is called.</p>
        <script>
            function myOpen() {
                window.open("Sample1.html", null, "height=400, width=800, status=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why have you named your windows as `null`?

Comment: If I add name in the second parameter, It still same, nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an open bug in MS Edge. The bug has already been filed here: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/2434857
Hope this helps to save you some time investigating the issue. Best, Malte

Answer (score 0):

I observed that second child window does not use `strWindowOptions` in the Microsoft Edge browser. However, it works when other browsers are used. I have spent lot of time on this and I would appreciate some help.